# Preventing output to /var/log/syslog

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I have rules such as:

```
 if $hostname startswith 'd.42ba7373' and $programname == 'app' then /var/log/applog
```

and don't want to output messages that go into that log to /var/log/syslog as well. Is that possible?

Comment: I see the same behaviour with lines like this in /etc/rsyslog.conf:

`$template FILENAME,"/var/log/remotes/%HOSTNAME%/syslog.log"`
`*.* ?FILENAME`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The discard (`~`) action may help.http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_actions.html

```
if $hostname startswith 'd.42ba7373' and $programname == 'app' then /var/log/applog
if $hostname startswith 'd.42ba7373' and $programname == 'app' then ~
```

Comment: This almost does what I personally need, but it's hard to make its behaviour nuanced: I basically want `/var/log/remotes/%HOSTNAME%/syslog.log` for remotes, but `/var/log/syslog` if it's from the master. I'm happy to hard-code the FQDN of the master in the config file todo this, but I can't figure out the conditionals.

Comment: @Cerales - how do you want this question answered? It's different than the one originally asked here, and you put a bounty on this Q. Seems like it should've been its own Q. I have some ideas on how to accomplish this but they don't fit this Q.

Comment: For folks viewing this answer in 2023, a modern rsyslog generates warnings when using ~, and offers that you should use 'stop' instead.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772654/rsyslog-server-saves-logs-from-remote-also-in-var-syslog). The above answer is going to work perfectly if the drop action is done in the main rsyslog conf file, which in case of ubuntu 14.04 with rsyslog 7.4.4 is `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. If anyone is using a separate conf file altogether, it should be named such that it comes before `50-default.conf` filename in the dictionary order, because the 50-default.conf file contains config for putting the logs to `/var/log/syslog`.